# How to zoom in and crop the SVG to specific coordinates in blazor

Tags: c#, image, svg, bitmap, blazor

I am getting the coordinates a1,y1,x2,y2,rotationangle,outputwidth and outputheight from user in my method.
I need to crop the svg using these coordinates but before cropping i need to zoom in the svg on these coordinates and then crop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A72nr.png)

```
     `double width = xaxis2 - xaxis1; double height = yaxis2 - yaxis1;              
            Rectangle CropArea = new Rectangle(

               Convert.ToInt32(xaxis1),
                   Convert.ToInt32(yaxis1),
                   Convert.ToInt32(width),
                   Convert.ToInt32(height)
                    );
            Bitmap originalImage = new Bitmap(filePath);
            using (Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(CropArea.Width, 
                   CropArea.Height))
            {

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(originalImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 
                 bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height), CropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }
            }`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. For your question to get some suggestions, you need to show us more. What have you tried so far? Could you show some sample code?

Comment: I have added the code.  let me know if need more information.